# How to use Type Parameter to handle any types in a tuple?

Tags: scala

I'm working on a problem from the book Learning Scala where it asks you to create a function where the input is a 2-tuple, and if either value is an `int` you return the `tuple` with the `int` in the first position.  I have something that works if they are both the same type, but cannot figure out how to make the types flexible enough to accept any input and then handle the return value possibly being switched.  I come from a Python background, so I'm just learning how to enforce such things:)

```
def intInFirst[A](x: (A, A)): (A, A) = {
  if (x._2.isInstanceOf[Int]) (x._2, x._1)
  else x
}

val x = (0, 0) // works
val y = ("hello", 15) // fails, should return (15, "hello")
```

Comment: First, by saying `x: (A, A)` you are saying that the input tuple `x` must have the same type in both positions. Thus it cannot accept `("hello", 15)` because the types are different. Second, if you fix my first point, then you can't do your tuple swap because your return type is different in each case of your `if`

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the original problem statement, as stated it doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @evan 7. Write a function that takes a 2-sized tuple and returns it with the Int value (if included) in the first position.

Comment: Interesting, well check my post below for an idea of how to solve that.

Comment: if you wanted to enforce a clause where one of the parameters needs to be an int but you don't want to specify, a better alternative would be to use currying and separate the parameters into two different parameter lists and have one of them be an int so that the user of the library can pass either parameter as they please `def f (x: Any)(y:Int)`, which would be far better than allowing the user to pass whatever and checking after the fact

Comment: @MrD Excellent, thank you!  I'm just starting the chapter on currying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat of my comment: by saying `x: (A, A)` you are saying that the input tuple `x` must have the same type in both positions. Thus it cannot accept `("hello", 15)` because the types are different.

Now to actually solve the problem, the only solution I can think of is to use the return type `(Any, Any)`:

```
scala> def intInFirst[A, B](x: (A, B)): (Any, Any) = 
     | x match {
     | case (_, b: Int) => x.swap
     | case _ => x
     | }
intInFirst: [A, B](x: (A, B))(Any, Any)

scala> intInFirst((1,2))
res2: (Any, Any) = (2,1)

scala> intInFirst((1,"apple"))
res4: (Any, Any) = (1,apple)

scala> intInFirst(("apple",1))
res5: (Any, Any) = (1,apple)
```

Also as a tip: most times where you find yourself about to use `isInstanceOf` or `asInstanceOf` think about what you are trying to accomplish and consider using pattern matching instead.

#### Edit:

This probably isn't what the question is going for but you could also use an `Either` for the return type:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def intInFirst[A, B](x: (A, B)): Either[(B, A), (A, B)] =
    x match {
        case (_, b: Int) => Left(x.swap)
        case _ => Right(x)
    }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

intInFirst: [A, B](x: (A, B))Either[(B, A),(A, B)]

scala> intInFirst((1,"apple"))
res1: Either[(String, Int),(Int, String)] = Right((1,apple))

scala> intInFirst((1,2))
res2: Either[(Int, Int),(Int, Int)] = Left((2,1))
```

`Either` is interesting because you can then pattern match on the output to find out which case was used:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

intInFirst((1,2)) match {
    case Left(a) => s"This value was swapped: $a"
    case Right(a) => s"This value was not swapped: $a"
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res3: String = This value was swapped: (2,1)

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

intInFirst((1,"apple")) match {
    case Left(a) => s"This value was swapped: $a"
    case Right(a) => s"This value was not swapped: $a"
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res4: String = This value was not swapped: (1,apple)
```

Answer (score 3):

The type `(A, A)` implies that both elements of the tuple have the same type. In other words, it will accept `(0, 0)` and `("hello", "world")` but not `("hello", 15)`. You can fix that by using a type `(A, B)`.

After that, the cleanest and easiest way to see if either element is an `Int`, is probably by using a pattern match instead of an `.isInstanceOf[Int]` check.

Comment: Note that using `isInstanceOf` breaks [parametricity](http://cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/05-type-classes.html).